# Trovebox (OpenPhoto) issues after fresh install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, open-source

After a fresh install of OpenPhoto on my Ubuntu 14.04 (x64) VPS I encountered the 'blank page @ step 3' error. Somehow I solved it (after several reinstalls, and fiddling with file/folder permissions).

Though solving the blank page.... Now other errors show up:

- Sorry, an error occured when trying to create your album.
- Could not update the status of this plugin.
- 1 New Feature On This Page link is not working
- Nothing happens when trying to upload a photo
- Photo uploaded by iOS app is shown, but cannot view view larger sizes...
- So far I have changed/tested: chmod +x all files/folders, chmod -R 775 all files/folders, chown www-data: files/folders, chmod 777 userdata cache photos

For now, I have restored a snapshot and started all over again. I gave extra attention to the installation of the json and mcrypt modules. The rest of the installation I followed the 'InstallationUbuntuApache' manual letter for letter.....

Unfortunately no succes.. Any help would be great

Comment: Also experiencing most of those issues as well. Will report back if I can figure out any of them. Also I'm not getting the Plupload plugin to show on the upload page, this happening to you as well?

Comment: Same here. Really struggling with this. It needs to be a Wordpress style install. Too much config required, and for people on shared hosting it is a nightmare.